# How do I parse uri?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, httpwebrequest

For the uri http://foo.com/apple/123

I want to get '123'.

According to the GAE documentation I can get the uri using self.request.get(), however is there a helper for just grabbing the sections of the uri?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using webapp, you can 'capture' parts of the regular expression that matches your handler, and they'll be passed to your handler as arguments. For example:

```
class FooHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, fruit, number):
    # Do something with your fruit and number (which are both strings, remember!)


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/([^/]+)/(\d+)', FooHandler),
])
```

Answer (score 5):

[Yes there is - the `urlparse` module](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) that comes with Python.  The `ParseResult` that you get back will strip off the host/protocol and such in a nice way, and then you can just use str's `split()` to split on the path separator.

Comment: @jaydel the "Yes there is" in my post *is* linky :)  (edit: extended the link a bit so it's more obvious)

Comment: Do you know if urlparse is part of Python 2.5?  If so what is the import path? Note I'm using Google App Engine.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried from urlparse import urlparse and it appears to be working.  I can't vote for the right answer for another 5 minutes it says . . .

Comment: Yeah, there's a 15(?) minute wait between asking a question and accepting an answer so that people can't spam and get rep :)  But you're correct that you have to use the `from .. import` syntax for this.

Comment: Well, "have to" is a bit strong. You could just `import urlparse` and then call it as `urlparse.urlparse`.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake, Daniel. I'm on a roll today :P